# How can I remove empty keys value from arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my output Arrays:

```
    Array
    (    
    [0] =>     
    [1] =>     
    [2] =>     
    [3] =>     
    [4] =>     
    [5] =>     
    [6] =>     
    [7] => 200    
    [8] => 200
    )
```

But I need only:
        [7] => 200
        [8] => 200

Any idea?

Comment: `array_filter($your_array)`

Comment: `print_r(array_filter($your_array));`

Comment: Can you please place your code with question?

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

For example,

```
$a= array
(    
 0 => '',    
 1 => '',   
 2 => '',  
 3 => '', 
 4 => '',
 5 => '',
 6 => '',
 7 => 200,  
 8 => 200,
);

print_r(array_filter($a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
print_r(array_filter($Array));
```